# Protect source code for auth-only routes in SSR Nuxt.js (or plain Vue.js)

Tags: security, authentication, vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I use an Express backend with the `nuxt.render` middleware to consolidate my API, front-end and development environment. So far, everything is going great, but I had some concerns about security concerning my auth setup.

My backend injects its user session into Vuex through a Nuxt middleware. While this works great for restricting access, the source code of those files is always available with a direct GET method. (e.g. if `/admin` is protected, `/_nuxt/admin.js` will still be available and will contain the entire source code of that page). Worst even, because of the default `preload` links put in the head by Nuxt, they will be automatically fetched, even if not logged in.

I understand that there are not a lot of security concerns with this because my admin API calls enforce the auth on the server side, but sometimes (as it is my case), exposing the source code is not desirable.

I have come up with a solution that works great, while being not very elegant:

1. In `nuxt.config.js`, I set `render.resourceHints = false`. I wish I didn't have to do this to benefit from the prefetching of available routes, but there seem to be no way to restrict the selection of prefetched routes.
2. Before plugging `next.render` into the Express' middleware chain, I selectively restrict the page's source code. (e.g. `app.get('/_nuxt/pages/admin.js', restrict)`, where `restrict` is a middleware that returns a `401` if not authenticated, or calls `next()` if it is. That prevents both XHR fetching and direct GET.)
3. I make a custom `error.vue` template, where I catch the error message Nuxt will throw if forced to access a route that the user shouldn't have access to, which looks like `Loading chunk 1 failed`, and normalize it to a "Forbidden" error page.

Is there a more pragmatic way of doing this that I miss, or is that outside the scope of what Nuxt.js provides at the moment?

Comment: I've also hit that giant roadblock and don't know what to do now.

Comment: Do you want to protect the front-end source code from user? It affirmative, well, it isn't possible.